# So how do i disable a script in untiy and enable it in the same public void(idk the name for it)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

I know how to disable it but I don't know how to enable it in the same void.

I have tried making another public void called playerRevive and in that put playerMovement.enabled = true;
and tried to enable it in the update method and it said this
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

what do I do

BTW it is a 2D game just for your information

Comment: Please add your code -> [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When an object is disabled it won't call its Awake/Start/Update methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Iggy said, you can't call MonoBehaviour methods from disabled objects. But you can reference this disabled object to another script and call method(s) from active object in the hierarchy.

Comment: btw it works. I had to make a method that enables it in another script and I had to call it in another script.

Comment: I am glad that solved your problem. Can you accept my comment as answer?